# BottomNavigationBar without Text

Tags: flutter

Yes, my question is this. How can I do like this?

[image]

I did a BottomNavigationBar but it looks like this.

[image]

My codes are like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.markunread),
        title: Text("Chat"),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
        title: Text("Your Country"),
      ),
    ],
    fixedColor: Colors.blue,
    onTap: clickedBottomBtn,
  ),
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set `showSelectedLabels` and `showUnselectedLabels` to `false:

```
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: 0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: // ...
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

**I think this is the better way**

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {},),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {},),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {},),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {},),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of **BottomNavigationBar** you cannot make the title of BottomNavigationBarItem null.

So here is the workaround.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                child: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              title: Container(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                child: Icon(Icons.markunread),
              ),
              title: Container(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                child: Icon(Icons.location_on),
              ),
              title: Container(),
            ),
          ],
          fixedColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
```

Comment: This will give the output what you shared in the question as expectation. If it is not able to give you the desired output, kindly post what exactly you want, so that I can help you.

Comment: This will give the output what you shared in the question as expectation. If it is not able to give you the desired output, kindly post what exactly you want, so that I can help you.

Comment: I just want an icon as bottom navigation bar item. I want no text. By the way, my English isn't good so I was hard to explain myself.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is `title: SizedBox.shrink()`

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer. Please, read the rules of this community.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `title:` attribute from `BottomNavigationBarItem`

Comment: cause i tried the same code and it worked , you can also try Text('') empty text field, maybe u have already tried this.

Comment: It looks like empty but there is a little space below.

Comment: Use `title: Container()`